# In Excel Pivot Table duplicates with spaces at the end appear

Tags: excel, pivot-table, trim

I have used the functions 'clean', 'trim' and 'substitute' to remove the spaces from my data, that I get as an export from another tool.

Even though, there should be no spaces left (I also checked this with the 'code' function and it DIDN'T have as a result 32 or 160), in my pivot table that I generate out of this data there are duplicates: one with a space at the end, and one without. I need to have the pivot table without the spaces.

The part I don't understand is, that when I create an additional column where I put in: `TRIM(A1)` (if A1 is the original cell where I have the function) and create the pivot table out of this additional column, every value appears only once and without any space!!!

My function I would like to use, but doesn't remove all spaces:

```
=CLEAN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(Table1!I2901;FIND("AM";Table1!I2901)+6;1));MID(Table1!I2901;FIND("AM";Table1!I2901);10-IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(Table1!I2901;FIND("AM";Table1!I2901)+8;1));0;IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(Table1!I2901;FIND("AM";Table1!I2901)+7;1));1;2)));"");"");"[ ]";"");CHAR(160);CHAR(32));CHAR(127);CHAR(32));CHAR(255);CHAR(32));"(";"");":";"");",";"");")";"");" ";"");"/";"");"T";"")))
```

Do you see a mistake?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Can I add an excel file in stack overflow? Is that possible and if yes how? I have to admit I don't know how to add one.

Comment: What EXCEL are you using? In Microsoft's EXCEL VBA , comma (",") is used to separate arguments.  What VBA are used??

Comment: Im using the german version. That`s why my arguments are seperated with ";" instead of ",". I forgot to translate this to the english version.

Comment: I am going to add a link in the next few minutes. Sorry that it takes so long @pnuts